# Migrating C++ ATL Executable application from VS2003 to VS2013

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, com, atl

I am migrating my C++ ATL Executable application from VS2003 to VS2013.

**In VS 2003**

*class CExeModule : public CComModule*

**In VS2013 (its been changed to)**

*class CExeModule : public ATL::CAtlExeModuleT< CExeModule >*

I have successfully migrated the project, during compilation i am facing a issue

**

> error C2664: 'ATL::CHandle::CHandle(HANDLE) throw()' : cannot convert
>   argument 1 from 'bool' to 'ATL::CHandle &'

**

I don't get this error if i comment the following code

_AtlModule.WinMain(nShowCmd);

**Can someone help here to solve this error ?**

> Additional info
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h(3628): error C2664: 'ATL::CHandle::CHandle(HANDLE) throw()' : cannot convert argument 1
>   from 'bool' to 'ATL::CHandle &' C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h(3608) : while compiling class
>   template member function 'HRESULT
>   ATL::CAtlExeModuleT::PreMessageLoop(int) throw()'
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h(3695) : see reference to function template instantiation 'HRESULT
>   ATL::CAtlExeModuleT::PreMessageLoop(int) throw()' being
>   compiled
>
> stdafx.h(107) : see reference to class template instantiation
>   'ATL::CAtlExeModuleT' being compiled

Comment: I suppose the problem is in your `CExeModule::PreMessageLoop` which you don't show.

Comment: I do not have any PreMessageLoop in my code...that is where i am surprised ...

Comment: Something else then interferes (some header included in stdafx.h or else where etc). You could create a clean ATL EXE project in VS2013 to make sure it build, and it is known to be buildable fine. The line with WinMain includes a chain of calls in this class which eventually hits a collision. I don't think the line is bad on its own (looks good).

Comment: Yes, i tried the same by creating a new ATL project in VS2013 , and found it is building fine (without adding any new code). and the line has nothing wrong "_AtlModule.WinMain(nShowCmd);"

Comment: The line it's choking on is `CHandle h(pT->StartMonitor());` Does `CExeModule` have a method `StartMonitor` returning `bool`, by any chance? Another possibility - do you maybe have a macro or a typedef redefining `HANDLE` somewhere in your program? Also check preprocessor definitions in project properties.

Comment: Yes i have a StartMonitor in my CExeModule...which returns bool... i will try to change the return type and confirm if it is fixed

Comment: Thanks Igor Tandetnik.... i solved the issue after changing the function name in the class CExeModule bool StratMonitor(). http://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Igor Tandetnik....

I solved the issue after changing the function name in the class CExeModule bool StratMonitor()